# Smooth scroll to anchor links in Nuxt3

Tags: nuxtjs3

Trying to use anchor links with smooth scrolling just like the React npm package "react-anchor-link-smooth-scroll", while there is a Vue3 equivalent, it does not work with Nuxt3, so what is the best way to employ smooth scrolling to anchor links?

Comment: Check some answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8816585+scroll

Comment: You can also probably try that one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73069885/8816585 And add `behavior: 'smooth'` to the answer.

Answer (score 11):

No need to use libraries, you can achieve this in every project with just 1 line of css:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: It depends. This one doesn't handle every possible use case.

Comment: @kissu which use cases don't get tackled by this? Seems to be working for me when using <nuxt-link> with a hash