# Nuxt.js 3 and on-site anchor navigation

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, anchor, nuxtjs3

I am learning Nuxt.js 3 and am writing a simple project with a one-scroll design that has a menu with anchor links. Clicking a link, the site should automatically scroll to the anchor (like a div with an id).
To test this I set up a simple Nuxt 3 installation with `npx nuxi init nuxt-app`, removed the demo content and replaced it with this:

`pages/index.vue`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div id="home"><p>hello world</p></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <nuxt-link :to="{ path: '/', hash: '#ciao' }">
        link
      </nuxt-link>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 3000px">placeholder</div>
    <div id="ciao"><p>ciao world</p></div>
    <div class="menu">
      <nuxt-link :to="{ path: '/', hash: '#home' }">
        link
      </nuxt-link>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 3000px">placeholder</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

The problem is, that it is not working. The url in the browser is changed to `localhost:3000/#ciao` or `localhost:3000/#home` on click. But the view is not being changed.

Is there something else I need to set up in nuxt, to get anchor navigation to work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As answered here: https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/5561#discussioncomment-3007717

Using a regular `a` tag solves the issue

```html
<a href="/#ciao">
  go to ciao's hash
</a>
```

---

Otherwise, you can also use

```html
<nuxt-link :to="{ hash: '#home' }" :external="true"> <!-- no need for a path if same page -->
  go to home's hash
</nuxt-link>
```

The `external` prop (Nuxt3 only) is detailed here: https://v3.nuxtjs.org/api/components/nuxt-link#props

Quote from the documentation

> Forces the link to be considered as external (true) or internal (false). This is helpful to handle edge-cases.