# Nuxt 3 Smooth Scrolling with Hash Links

Tags: scroll, routes, anchor, nuxtjs3

In my Nuxt.js 3 project, I want to implement single-page navigation. And I followed following articles but it didn't work. any suggestions?

- https://dev.to/dimer191996/nuxt-js-smooth-scrolling-with-hash-links-94a
- https://levelup.gitconnected.com/nuxt-js-how-to-retain-scroll-position-when-returning-to-page-without-navigation-history-7f0250886d27

Comment: Hi, what is not working exactly on your side? Did you tried that one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73893669/8816585 And this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73069885/8816585

Comment: when I click my nav item it will not navigation to particular anchortag position.
`<nuxt-link :to="{ path: '/', hash: menuItem.url }">{{
            menuItem.label
          }}</nuxt-link>`

Comment: Did you checked my given links? Also, please add more details regarding your setup, right now it's still quite vague.

Comment: yes this ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73069572/nuxt-js-3-and-on-site-anchor-navigation/73069885#73069885) worked. thanks

Comment: But do you know how to add a smooth transition for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to do it in Nuxt.js 3 is to create the "router.scrollBehaviour.js" file in the `plugins/` directory. Its content should be

```js
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from "#app";

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.$router.options.scrollBehavior = async (to, from, savedPosition) => {
    if (savedPosition) {
      return savedPosition;
    }

    const findEl = async (hash, x = 0) => {
      return (
        document.querySelector(hash) ||
        new Promise((resolve) => {
          if (x > 0) {
            return resolve(document.querySelector("#app"));
          }
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(findEl(hash, 1));
          }, 300);
        })
      );
    };

    if (to.hash) {
      const el = await findEl(to.hash);

      if ("scrollBehavior" in document.documentElement.style) {
        console.log("hash path hit scroll to");
        return window.scrollTo({ top: el.offsetTop, behavior: "smooth" });
      } else {
        return window.scrollTo(0, el.offsetTop);
      }
    }
    return { left: 0, top: 0, behaviour: "smooth" };
  };
})
```

Comment: I do not recommend using querySelectors but I guess that it's working for you right now.

Comment: @kissu Could you elaborate why you don't recommend using querySelectors?

Comment: @CyrilN. Vue is based on working with state, while query selectors have their own DOM manipulation kind of approach, mixing both will not be friendly if you want to pass the data back and forth. You can make something reactive with a ref tho, probably the best approach overall. Or even VueUse composables. 

Comment: @kissu in the above case, the dom is used to retrieve information, not too manipulate it, so it shouldn't pose any issues. But I agree with you that it shouldn't be used for dom manipulation.

Comment: @CyrilN. You can just stick to a template ref in the same manner, no need to switch context.

Answer (score 2):

2024 Update: You can now configure this inside your `nuxt.config.ts`:
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/going-further/custom-routing#scroll-behavior-for-hash-links

```js
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  router: {
    options: {
      scrollBehaviorType: 'smooth'
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: But when I add this configuration I get below error

Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'scrollBehaviorType' does not exist in type '{ end?: boolean | undefined; sensitive?: boolean | undefined; strict?: boolean | undefined; linkActiveClass?: string | undefined; linkExactActiveClass?: string | undefined; hashMode?: boolean | undefined; }'.

it seems like this option is not available anymore

Comment: @SathyaMolagoda which version of Nuxt are you on? Here is a reproduction with the latest version (3.11.1), and it works: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-2nly9x?file=nuxt.config.ts

Comment: I think may that is the issue, I'm using 3.4.3

Answer (score 1):

In Nuxt.js 3 you can do this without a plugin. Simply place a "app/router.options.ts" within the root of your project and add following code to it:

```
    import type { RouterConfig } from "@nuxt/schema";
    
    export default {
      scrollBehavior(to, from, savedPosition) {
        if(savedPosition)
          return savedPosition;
    
        if (to.hash && to.path == from.path) {
           const el = document.querySelector(to.hash);
        return { top: el.offsetTop, left: 0, behavior: "smooth" };
        }
    
        return {
          top: 0,
          left: 0
        }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Define pulgin file for Nuxt3 in
plugins/scroll-behavior.client.ts like [Kaiser mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76462819/13526708),
But I had to modify it to work for Nuxt3. The main difference that you should use beforeEach to call your animation before the transition actually happens. Otherwise you end up trying to animate position that is alredy there. The delay promise makes up transition time, if you make it shorter, transition would be faster. This works for single page just fine, but may require upgrades for navigating anchors between pages.

```
      export default defineNuxtPlugin(async function () {
          if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        
            const router = useRouter();
        
            router.beforeEach((to) => {
              if (to.hash) {
                const targetElement = document.querySelector(to.hash);
                if (targetElement) {
                  targetElement.scrollIntoView({
                      behavior: "smooth"
                  })
                  const p:Promise<boolean> = new Promise((resolve)=>{
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                      resolve(true);
                    },1000)
                  })
                  return p
                }
              }
        
              window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
            });
          }
        });
```

And set up the plugin in nuxt.config.ts like mentioned before:

```
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/scroll-behavior.client.ts', mode: 'client' }
  ]
```

Then you can use your navigation with hashes like this:

```
<NuxtLink :to="{path: '/', hash: '#anchor1'}">
          <div class="button">Link 1</div>
</NuxtLink>

...

<div id="anchor1"> Target content block </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a plugin isn't the way to do it in Nuxt 3 - have a look right here: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/22663

Answer (score 0):

i prefer this:

plugins/scroll-behavior.client.ts

```js
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

export default async function () {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    const router = useRouter();

    router.afterEach(async (to, from) => {
      if (to.hash) {
        const targetElement = document.querySelector(to.hash);

        if (targetElement) {
          await targetElement.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: "smooth",
            block: "start",
            inline: "nearest",
          });
          return;
        }
      }

      window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
    });
  }
}
```

in the nuxt.config.ts add this:

```js
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/scroll-behavior.client.ts', mode: 'client' }
  ]
```

then, in your component, reference something with an id, let's say id="about"
heres a button on the page that will smoothly put the about hash in display.

```html
<nuxt-link :to="{ hash: '#about' }" class="btn btn-lg btn-warning mx-1">Learn more</nuxt-link>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are using tailwind, you can make use of [Scroll Behavior](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scroll-behavior). Just add `"scroll-smooth"` class name to the html element using "useHead" composable.

```
<script setup>
useHead({
  htmlAttrs: {
    class: 'scroll-smooth'
  },
})
</script>
```